# OpenGL Invalid Operation with GenVertexArrays

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I am creating a grid in opengl, very simple, but am getting an error when I call gl::GenVertexArrays.  Below is the code.  I am using glfw3.

```
GLuint vao = 0;
check_gl_error();
gl::GenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
check_gl_error(); //the error is caught here and its a INVALID_OPERATION
gl::BindVertexArray(vao);
check_gl_error();
```

I do not have much experience with OpenGL, however I have used opengl on the same computer using glfw and have had projects working with GenVertexArrays.

EDIT:

My program is setup with

```
if (!glfwInit()) {
  std::cout << "Init GLFW failed" << std::endl;
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 800, "My Title", NULL, NULL);    //glfwGetPrimaryMonitor() full screen
if (!window) {
  std::cout << "Init window failed" << std::endl;
  glfwTerminate();
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
gl::sys::LoadFunctions();

//check_gl_error();

glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
check_gl_error();

glfwSwapInterval(1);
check_gl_error();

GLuint programID = gl::CreateProgram();
```

Comment: Don't spam `check_gl_error` everywhere, you should set up a debug context using glfw hints. You need to setup the error callbacks, the errors will automatically call the error callback. Did you make the context current?

Comment: [It was made part of core in OpenGL 1.1](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/debug_output.txt). It will almost certainly be available, and it is incredibly helpful to have the driver verify things and catch bugs quickly and accurately.

Comment: @doug65536 I did make the context current with glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);.  Its like the 10th line of code in my program and occurs before the code I posted above.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glGenVertexArrays) `INVALID_OPERATION` is only thrown if the count parameter is negative

Answer (score 1):

Do you use GLEW or glLoadGen or something? You need to tell it to update its entry points again *after* you make the actual context current.

In Windows, only ancient OpenGL is available until you make a more modern context current. Only then will the higher-version entry points become available for lookup by GLEW/glLoadGen's code.

In other words, all those OpenGL function pointers suddenly may point to different code, because the OpenGL version changed. That is how wgl works.